# How does canvas remove the line at the connection？android canvas

Tags: android

```
private Point[] initPoint() {
    Point[] points = new Point[6];
    int[] location1 = {(int) mOneView.getX(), (int) mOneView.getY()};
    int[] location2 = {(int) mTwoView.getX(), (int) mTwoView.getY()};
    int[] location3 = {(int) mThreeView.getX(), (int) mThreeView.getY()};
    int[] location4 = {(int) mFourView.getX(), (int) mFourView.getY()};
    int[] location5 = {(int) mFiveView.getX(), (int) mFiveView.getY()};
    int[] location6 = {(int) mSixView.getX(), (int) mSixView.getY()};
    
    points[0] = new Point(location1[0] + mOneView.getWidth() / 2, location1[1] + mOneView.getWidth() / 2);
    points[1] = new Point(location2[0] + mTwoView.getWidth() / 2, location2[1] + mTwoView.getWidth() / 2);
    points[2] = new Point(location3[0] + mThreeView.getWidth() / 2, location3[1] + mThreeView.getWidth() / 2);
    points[3] = new Point(location4[0] + mFourView.getWidth() / 2, location4[1] + mFourView.getWidth() / 2);
    points[4] = new Point(location5[0] + mFiveView.getWidth() / 2, location5[1] + mFiveView.getWidth() / 2);
    points[5] = new Point(location6[0] + mSixView.getWidth() / 2, location6[1] + mSixView.getWidth() / 2);
    return points;
```

}

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {    //每次滑动完连接点就重新显示出来
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    Point[] points = initPoint();
    Point startp;
    Point endp;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
        startp = points[i];
        endp = points[i + 1];
        int wt = (startp.x + endp.x) / 2;
        Point p3 = new Point();
        Point p4 = new Point();
        p3.y = startp.y;
        p3.x = wt;
        p4.y = endp.y;
        p4.x = wt;
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(startp.x, startp.y);
        path.cubicTo(p3.x, p3.y, p4.x, p4.y, endp.x, endp.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQmNh.png)

--- I want to remove the connecting line in the circle of the marked box in the picture, but I am not familiar with canvas, thank you for your advice ---

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks to me, like this can be done in the setup of the canvas. Please include a minimal working example (e.g. 3 Points) and the setup code for your canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas` has nothing to do in here, its just math... between two neighbor points you are drawing curved line (`for` loop) - from center of one circle to center of second circle. so you should calculate points on circumferences of these circles and draw line between them, no centers

above will need some math, but there is probably an easier way - first draw these lines, then draw points, which should be fulfilled with same color as background (so white in here). this will make inner space of circle cover part of line drawn under it to the center of circle. easiest way would be to move `super.dispatchDraw(canvas);` to the end of method causing your drawing `for` loop to be executed at first (also remeber to fulfil circles if they are transparent with stroke)